# Hosting asp.net website with database

Tags: asp.net, hosting

I have created one asp.net website (project) with the help of Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. The database of the respective project is designed with the help of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008. Now I want to publish the website on the internet. Can somebody please guide me in this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a bit broad, and Stack Overflow doesn't generally provide end-to-end tutorials like that.  It's possible that someone may provide one, and it's possible that what they provide may coincidentally make all the correct assumptions about your application and environment.  But it's unlikely.  Where specifically are you stuck with this?  What have you tried?  Visual Studio has "publish" functionality built into the context menu, you can right-click on the project in the solution explorer and "publish" (or "deploy" depending on the Visual Studio version).

Comment: Yes David Sir. I tried that. But what about database? How can I integrate the database (present in the default location of SQL Server) with the website while hosting?

Comment: The hosted website would use its own database.  What kind of database are you using?  SQL Server?  A database file?  Something else?  If you're using SQL Server then the hosted site would need access to a hosted SQL Server.  If you're using a file then a copy of that file would need to be deployed with the application.  All that would be different in either case is the connection string in the `Web.Config` file.  Generally this would be managed by the `Web.config` transform files, which are unique per build configuration.

Comment: I have created database with the help of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. So, do I need to upload database file separately rather than the website?

Comment: If the database isn't a file but rather an actual SQL Server database then you wouldn't "upload" it per se.  You'd *deploy* the database.  How are you *tracking* the database schema?  If you're using a database project in Visual Studio (recommended) then you'd publish that just like publishing an application.  If you're just tracking a bunch of database scripts then you'd execute those scripts on the server database.  If you're creating the database manually (not recommended) then you'd create the production database manually as well.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need a **Windows** hosting provider (a provider that uses windows servers) that supports all the technologies you used (MVC maybe?)
2. Remove all debugging code (if any) from your application and modify the web.config as needed
3. upload the whole project folder (without the .sln file) to the server and try to run the website
4. if you run into an error, ask a good question on stackoverflow :-)

Please note: StackOverflow is not a tutorial site and is only for specific questions like "What and where are the stack and heap?" not "How to write a hello world application in C#". While I am answering this question, please avoid asking such broad questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Consider trying azure.

You get more control over what you do and its really simple to publish

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/

Azure hosts its own database so you just move your tables into it.. there are a ton of guides on how to start this