# How to Publish Website and its Database (ASP.net and SQL Server) on the internet

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web, connection-string

i would like to ask you Guys ,

i'm planing to Build a Website using ASP.net and SQL Server ,

i have an idea about how to publish the Website online but could anyone explain to me in more Details,how can i publish my website and its Database Online

and in the website i've to use Specific ConnectionString during my Work locally on my database so what will be the ConnectionString once the Database and the website Published Online

i really appreciate if you could help me on this Topic

best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to  **azure**.

You get more control over what you do and its really simple to publish

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/

Azure hosts its own database so you just move your tables into it.. there are a ton of guides on how to start this

**Hosting asp.net website with database**
[Hosting asp.net website with database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26339246/hosting-asp-net-website-with-database)